# How to convert System.Uri to string

Tags: vb.net, string, uri, httprequest

So what I am trying to achieve is to make textbox1 have text input in it. Then when button1 is clicked it will test to show if the textbox1.text (www.google.com, www.youtube.com etc) depending on the textbox1.text, if the website is online or not.

```
 Dim url As New System.Uri(TextBox1.Text) 'This is the line that I want to be textbox1.text instead of a url

    Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest

    req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url)

    Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse

    ServerListBox1.Text = "Checking " + TextBox1.Text + "..."


    Try

        resp = req.GetResponse()

        resp.Close()

        req = Nothing

        ServerListBox1.Items.Add("[+] Server " + TextBox1.Text + " Is Online [+]")

    Catch ex As Exception

        req = Nothing

        Return

        ServerListBox1.Items.Add("[-] Server " + TextBox1.Text + " Is Offline [-]")

    End Try
```

Comment: What is your problem / your error? Please extend your question

Comment: "*How to convert System.Uri to string*" : how about [`myUri.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.uri.tostring)?

Comment: Thank you for your help guys! but i found an alternate way!